# How to encrypt a string using sha-1 by passing key?

Tags: java, android, sha1

I'm trying to encrypt a string message to get same encrypted code for same string message in my app. How can i get the same encrypted code using same key?

Below is my code. It is generating encrypted code but it does not match with that code which is generated at server

```
 public  String SHAsum(String convertme) {
           MessageDigest md = null;
           byte[] data;
        try {
            md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            data=convertme.getBytes("utf8");
            md.update(data);
            md.hashCode();

            //md.update( key.getBytes() );
            return new BigInteger( 1, md.digest() ).toString(16);


        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } //This could also be SHA1withDSA, no exception handling
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";

        }
```

---

```
String password="qqqqq"; 
byte[] salt="guVoUubWwvniR2G0FgaC9".getBytes(); 
String abc=""; 
try 
  { 
    abc = getHash( password, salt); 
    System.out.println("Encypted password is -------------->"+abc); 
  } 

catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
    e1.printStackTrace(); 
} 

catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) 
{
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
   e1.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

Comment: Hashing isn't generally termed "encryption" in that you can't *decrypt* a hash. It's cryptography, but usually encryption is two-way. Do you have an example of what your code produces (for a particular string) vs what the server shows you? And do you *really* want to just return "" if something goes wrong?

Comment: Actually user password present in php server in the form of sha-1 hashing, i want to do like this, in my app if some one enter password then it will be converted in to sha-1 hashing using same salt,but i unable to get the same hash code after hashing....

Comment: Fine... but could you give sample input and server output? Maybe there's a bug in the PHP code for example. We can easily try this with other tools to see which output is correct.

Comment: String password="qqqqq";
    byte[] salt="guVoUubWwvniR2G0FgaC9".getBytes();
    String abc="";
    try {
     abc = getHash( password, salt);
     System.out.println("Encypted password is -------------->"+abc);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e1.printStackTrace();
    }

Comment: public String getHash(String password, byte[] salt) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        digest.reset();
        digest.update(password.getBytes());
        digest.update(salt);
        
        return (new BigInteger( 1, digest.digest() ).toString(16)).toString();

        //return digest.digest(password.getBytes("UTF-8"));
  }

Comment: In the above method i able to create  a hash code for password "qqqq" but it not match with previously created hashcode for pwd "qqqq" which is present in server database

Comment: @Narenda: For the third time, could you please tell us what hash *is* in the server database? Without having a sample which we're trying to match against, we can't easily tell whether the PHP hash is as-expected.

Comment: A thought.  You should check whether the salt is placed before or after the text.  Having them in the wrong order will give a different hash.

Comment: @Narendra were you able to get an answer to this thread?